# Getting document.observe is not a function when implementing endless page from Railscast 114

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

Rails and programming beginner here.

I'm trying to implement endless page from Railscast 114 but it isn't loading. Firebug console brings up an error:

> document.observe is not a function - document.observe('dom:loaded',
>   checkScroll);

Have tried searching for reasons why other than not having Prototype loaded, but the HTML shows that it is loaded. Also tried adding the format part in the controller suggested in another answer but it doesn't seem to work.

The code is a bit different from Ryan's as I'm rendering from a feed.

_feed.html.erb

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'endless_page', 'prototype' %>
  <div id="promotions" summary="Status feed">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

 def home
    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?
      @promotion = Promotion.new
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    end    
 end
```

endless_page.js

```
var currentPage = 1;

function checkScroll() {
  if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
    currentPage++;
    new Ajax.Request('/?page=' + currentPage, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'GET'});
  } else {
    setTimeout("checkScroll()", 250);
  }
}

function nearBottomOfPage() {
  return scrollDistanceFromBottom() < 150;
}

function scrollDistanceFromBottom(argument) {
  return pageHeight() - (window.pageYOffset + self.innerHeight);
}

function pageHeight() {
  return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', checkScroll);
```

feed.js.rjs

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :promotions, :partial => @feed_items
if @feed_items.total_pages > @feed_items.current_page
  page.call 'checkScroll'
else
  page[:loading].hide
end
```